# Convertir con la función CAST un tipo de dato a otro, en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Estoy tratando de crear una vista en Azure Synapse Analytics, en donde lee datos de una tabla llamada *tabla1* que se encuentra en storage account. La *tabla1* contiene una columna llamada *fecha*, no se sabe bien el formato, puede ser datatime2 o varchar. El formato de la columna *fecha* de *tabla1* aparece con este formato:  `2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000`. Luego en la vista se necesita aplicar un cast para convertir el tipo de dato que tiene, y convertirlo  al tipo tipo de dato DATE con longitud de 10 y con el formato yyyy-MM-dd.

Intenté implementar el cast de la siguiente manera pero no funciona, ya que al consultar la vista, el formato de fecha sigue apareciendo como en la tabla llamada *tabla1* (`2019-01-01T00:00:00.0000000`).

¿Cómo se puede hacer un cast y convertir el dato correspondiente?

A continuación se presenta el código que implementé:

*Este es el formato como aparece en *tabla1*: `2019-03-01 00:00:00.0000000`, el objetivo es convertir a yyyy-mm-dd, tipo de dato como date y de longitud de 10

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), [Mes], 120) AS DATE) AS Mes //Intento que no funciono
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vistaEjemplo]
AS SELECT
cast([fecha]                              as [Date](10))      AS fecha, //
FROM
   OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'ruta/DeLaTabla/Origen', //Ruta donde se encuentra la tabla1
        DATA_SOURCE = '.......',  //Especifica la fuente
        FORMAT='DELTA'
    )WITH(
    [Mes]                               varchar(64),
    ) vistaEjemplo
```

Answer (score 0):

Has probado de la siguiente manera?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vistaEjemplo]
AS 
SELECT
    CAST(CONVERT(DATE, [fecha], 126) AS DATE) AS fecha
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'ruta/DeLaTabla/Origen', 
        DATA_SOURCE = '.......',
        FORMAT = 'DELTA'
    )
    WITH (
        [fecha] VARCHAR(64)
    )
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu apoyo, Es buena respuesta, claro que lo intente, con esta forma si aparecen, es una respuesta valida, igual encontre otra forma valida, Intente con TRY CAST( [Fecha] as date)     AS Fecha